# Where does Django store generated tokens resp. token links?

Tags: python, django, authentication, token

I am currently programming a Django app & have now also included email verification.
In doing so, I have shamelessly used Djangos' token generator and misused it for my own purposes. This worked because an email verification works very similar to a password reset:

- A user enters his data in a form
- An email is sent
- The user clicks on the hash link
- The link verifies the user's input

But now I ask myself where Django stores these tokens or links? There is an expire value in the settings ([PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout)) but as I look up the generator([PasswordResetTokenGenerator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py)) it is just used for comparison.

This leads me to the question: Where does Django store these links? Do they ever expire? What happens if I generate an account & never click the email link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokens generated by `PasswordResetTokenGenerator` are not stored anywhere. The token *itself* has a timestamp in it. If we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d270dd584e0af12fe6229fb712d0704c232dc7e5/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L62-L72) method that makes the token, it is implemented as:

> ```
> def _make_token_with_timestamp(self, user, timestamp):
>     # timestamp is number of seconds since 2001-1-1. Converted to base 36,
>     # this gives us a 6 digit string until about 2069.
>     ts_b36 = int_to_base36(timestamp)
>     hash_string = salted_hmac(
>         self.key_salt,
>         self._make_hash_value(user, timestamp),
>         secret=self.secret,
>         algorithm=self.algorithm,
>     ).hexdigest()[::2]  # Limit to shorten the URL.
>     return "%s-%s" % (ts_b36, hash_string)
> ```

Here the value `timestamp` passed to the method is the current timestamp, you can see it makes a `hash_string` using this timestamp and some of the users data itself (the users pk, hashed password, last login timestamp, email), if any of these values change our token becomes invalid. At the end you can see it returns `"%s-%s" % (ts_b36, hash_string)` which is just a string of the form `<timestamp>-<hash_string>`. So when we receive the token from the user, checking it is as simple as checking if the timestamp is not too old, taking the timestamp, the user object (we get it from the *other* parameter we receive i.e. `uidb64`) and recomputing the `hash_string` and checking if they match.

So these links are not stored anywhere, yes they expire, if you generate an account and never use the link it will expire and you cannot use it, if you want you can allow the user to generate a new link by writing some more code.

Comment: Ah, of course. The token it self contains the necessary data. Therefore no need for storing anything. This makes sense. Thank you.